# TK102-2 Tracker in PHP

Tags: php, gps, server, tracker

I want to create a server in PHP that read the latitude and longitude recived from the GPS Tracker.

I dont know how I can read this coords. I'm using a tracker online and is working but I want to do my tracker in PHP.

How I can do it?

Comment: please I need to know if I must use php socket with tcp protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use TCP sockets. You will also require detailed data protocol document from the tracker manufacturer. The data protocol tells you everything you need to know about reading and writing to socket.